# ReactJs Web client + Ruby-on-Rails API server - Authentication with facebook & google_oauth2 using Devise + OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, devise, omniauth

Client-side, I am able to connect to facebook or google_oauth2 with OmniAuth. But server-side, I have an `Authentication failure!` (for different reasons depending on authentication type).

I followed the Devise guide to integrate with Omniauth ([here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)), taking into account Omniauth's recommendations when integrating into a Rails API ([here](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth)).

---React App---

src/components/socialAuth/SocialAuth.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login'
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login'

export default ({ handleLogInWithProvider }) => {
  const responseFacebook = response => {
    console.log('facebook', response)
    handleLogInWithProvider('facebook', response)
  }

  const responseGoogle = response => {
    console.log('google_oauth2', response)
    handleLogInWithProvider('google_oauth2', response)
  }

  return (
    <div className="social-auth">
      <FacebookLogin
        appId="XXXXXX"
        autoLoad={true}
        scope="email,public_profile"
        fields="email,name,picture"
        callback={responseFacebook}
      />
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="XXXXXX"
        responseType="code"
        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

src/ducks/auth.js

```js
export const logInWithProvider = (provider, response) => async dispatch => {
  const endpoint = `/users/auth/${provider}/callback`
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(response),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  try {
    const responseAPI = await dispatch(fetch({ endpoint, options }))
    console.log(responseAPI)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

The console shows that both Facebook and Google return a complete hash (with credentials and user profile info)...

---RoR API---

Gemfile

```rb
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```rb
  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  facebook_app_id = Rails.application.credentials
                         .apis[:facebook][:oauth2][:app_id]
  facebook_app_secret = Rails.application.credentials
                             .apis[:facebook][:oauth2][:app_secret]
  google_app_id = Rails.application.credentials
                       .apis[:google][:oauth2][:app_id]
  google_app_secret = Rails.application.credentials
                           .apis[:google][:oauth2][:app_secret]

  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'
  config.omniauth :facebook,
                  facebook_app_id,
                  facebook_app_secret,
                  scope: 'email'
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
                  google_app_id,
                  google_app_secret,
                  name: 'google',
                  # Temporary fix for `Authentication failure! csrf_detected`...
                  provider_ignores_state: Rails.env.development?
```

app/config/application.rb

```rb
    # To integrate OmniAuth into a Rails API.
    config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, config.session_options
```

app/models/user.rb

```rb
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook google_oauth2]
```

config/routes.rb

```rb
  devise_for :users,
             only: :omniauth_callbacks,
             controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/omniauth_callbacks' }
```

app/controllers/v1/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```rb
module V1
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
      handle_omniauth
    end

    def google
      handle_omniauth
    end

    private

    # Provide central callback for OmniAuth.
    def handle_omniauth
      puts auth
      ...
    end

    def auth
      request.env['omniauth.auth']
    end
  end
end
```

In the rails console, I have different error messages for Facebook and for Google as I request different authentication strategies, using One-time Code Flow (Hybrid Authentication) with Google.

- For Facebook:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! no_authorization_code: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError, must pass either a `code` (via URL or by an `fbsr_XXX` signed request cookie)
```

- For Google:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

I found kind of a workaround by adding `provider_ignores_state: true` in the Devise initializer but it doesn't seem to be secure...

config/initializers/devise.rb

```rb
    config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
                  google_app_id,
                  google_app_secret,
                  name: 'google',
                  # Temporary fix for `Authentication failure! csrf_detected`...
                  provider_ignores_state: Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: I guess you'll want to figure out why `request.env['omniauth.auth']` is `nil`. Are you seeing errors in your developer console (browser) or server console?

Comment: I edited my post with additional information...

Comment: @YassineDM did you ever get this working? If so, it would be great to post your answer

Comment: Unfortunately no, I went with Auth0...